# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn’t ‘website_ids’ property

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, soap, magento

i am struggling to get the products listed/called from magneto via SOAP.  I am using the following statement please help, tell me what i am doing wrong.

I am sending down the username and apikey vi the “LogInSession.Session()” method, it just keeps the connection info.

```
string sessionId = LogInSession.Session();
MagentoSOAPv2.MagentoService ms = new MagentoSOAPv2.MagentoService();
var productList = ms.catalogProductList(sessionId, new MagentoSOAPv2.filters(), storeView: "1");

            foreach (var pi in productList)
            {
                Response.Write("category_ids" + pi.category_ids + "<br/>");
                Response.Write("name" + pi.name + "<br/>");
                Response.Write("product_id" + pi.product_id + "<br/>");
                Response.Write("set" + pi.set + "<br/>");
                Response.Write("sku" + pi.sku + "<br/>");
                Response.Write("type" + pi.type + "<br/>");
                Response.Write("website_ids" + pi.website_ids + "<br/>");
            }
```

Comment: i found the solution, its probably only a error for version 1.3, they probably fixed it in the stable 1.4.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=6614

there is 2 files to change, the v2.php
and wsdl.xml

Full details are in the link i suplied above

Answer (score 0):

Try to change website_ids with store_id. I didn't heard so far of website_ids in the api docs, but I am pretty new to magento myself.